# How does this Dyson Airwrap work?

Tags: consumer-electronics, heat

so I’ve been looking into Dyson a lot, and how their stuff works (like AirWrap) and I came across like this picture:[image]

Is that bit I circled a heating part please? How can it heat, it just looks like a metal grating? Also what is that golden chip towards the right please?

Also please, I know that this doesn’t allow extreme heat, does it have sensors for this and other sensors maybe too?

Comment: you already asked this question ... why are you asking again?

Comment: sorry new here, didn’t know this was asked before. Can you share link please?

Comment: I saw a post with the exact same picture asking a similar question, maybe even the same question ... where did you get the picture?

Comment: The gold chip is most likely any ordinary computerchip that was colored gold by the marketing department to look more impressive.

Comment: Hi, if you search on Google, Dyson Airwrap, the stack exchange one came up in images and I just didn’t edit the circle. But I had the same question too anyway. I couldn’t find another image like it, I mean that shows inside